# Get paths of all open webforms

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a project to QA all of our open webforms. We have about two screens (using the default pager) of open webforms.

The simple-but-hard way is to copy each link, but I wonder if there is an easier way. Can I programmatically pull up the path for all open webforms? Or is there a module?

I looked at building a view of webforms, but there was only an option to create a view of webform submissions, not of webforms themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a custom module using `entity.query` service

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->getQuery();
$webform_ids = $query->condition('status', 'open')->execute();

$webforms = Webform::loadMultiple($webform_ids);
$webform_urls = [];
foreach($webforms as $webform){
  $webform_urls[] = $webform->toUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString();
}
```

Here is a [demo module](https://github.com/GiorgosK/webform_links) that uses `entity.query` in a controller to output those path as links with title as the title of each webform.

Comment: I've never had someone write a module based on my question! Thanks : D

Comment: I've started a bounty so I can reward you for your above-and-beyond effort : )

Comment: Its a nice gesture, thanks. Drupal has always been helpful to me, just trying to give back as much as I can.

Comment: I meant the Drupal community.